# Why axios delete with interceptors doesnt work?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, axios

I am making a simple delete request but my backend route is never reached and I dont know what I am doing wrong. Any help would be great!!

```
const instance = axios.create({
    baseURL: 'http://13axxxxx.ngrok.io'
});

instance.interceptors.request.use(
    async (config) => {
        const token = await AsyncStorage.getItem("token");
        if (token) {
            config.headers.Authorization = `Bearer ${token}`;
        }
        return config;
    },
    (err) => {
        return Promise.reject(err);
    }
);

export default instance;
```

```
import BaseAPI from './BaseAPI';
const delete = () => {
  return BaseAPI.delete('/delete_account');
}
```

in my backend this route is never hit:

```
 app.use(router.delete('delete_account', (req, res, next) => {
        console.log("delete called")
    }))
```

Answer (score 1):

The issue here is that you’ve missed the starting “/“ in your

```
router.delete(“/…”)
```